# jQuery: setInterval effects on the server?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if this question is not suitable or too broad for STO but I can't find any information about this so I need to ask here.

This might be a silly question  to some and I think I know the answer but just to make sure, I was wondering what is the effects of using `setInterval` on my VPS server.

I.e. does it take a lot of resources out of my server?

It is **NOT** an AJAX. its just a very basic setInterval like this:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    $('.mydiv').remove();   
}, 500);
```

I know this is just a client side code but I was just wondering if it still has any effects on my server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `javascript` at Question does not appear to request further resources from server. What is purpose of using `setInterval` where calling `.remove()` within function?

Comment: @guest271314, the purpose is to keep the function running constantly to make sure the element myDiv always removed.

Answer (score 2):

you answer your question yourself: "I know this is just a client side code". It has nothing to do with server side. your server doesn't know what is going on in client browsers. Depending on the callback function of the setInterval it can only affect on browser performance

Answer (score 1):

The above jquery execution does not have any effects on the server.  The only effect could be when the page is requested and the jquery file gets downloaded. The jquery execution is completely client side unless you make an ajax call or something to server.